# Is it possible to filter rostopic echo by node?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lets suppose that node A and B are publishing to a topic T, is it possible to use rostopic echo to show only what node B is publishing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335993/is-it-possible-to-filter-rostopic-echo-by-node?/) by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2019-10-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matosinho](https://answers.ros.org/users/47762/matosinho/) on 2019-10-23**:
Same trouble here t-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, I don't believe that is currently supported (as of Kinetic/Melodic).

`rostopic echo` does support a `--filter` expression:

```
  --filter=FILTER-EXPRESSION
                        Python expression to filter messages that are printed.
                        Expression can use Python builtins as well as m (the
                        message) and topic (the topic name).
```

However I don't believe that has access to message metadata (as opposed to the message data itself) which is what you would need.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2